# Solve $y'= \frac{(x+y)^2}{2}.$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Setting $z(x)=x+y(x)$ I get $y'=z'-1$ and

$$z'=1+\frac{z^2}{2},$$

But I'm not sure how I should separate this.

Comment: Just divide by the entire RHS. There's no $x$ relation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\frac{dz}{dx} = 1+\frac{z^2}{2}$

$2\int \frac{dz}{2 + z^2} = x$

The LHS can be integrated with a tangent sub after a little manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straight forward since the RHS is only a function of $z$

$$ \frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{2 + z^2}{2} $$

$$ \frac{2}{2+z^2}dz = dx $$